# Email in Flutter Web without using password or any sensitive data

Tags: flutter, email, passwords, sendgrid, flutter-web

I want to send an email using Flutter Web without using a password or any sensitive data as I have hosted my webpage using GitHub Pages and I want it to be open source. Also, using direct passwords in code may lead to data leaks. Any ideas what should I do? As if I use things like 'SendGrid then in that case the API needs to be a secret. I need emails for notification to myself, so even a special case will work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a generalized answer to it. But if you want a special case and need emails for notification to just yourself then in that case you can use **EmailJS**. It is a client-side service and you can set a template for your use.

You may refer to this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDwst9icjAY

But you need to make sure that 'to_parameter' is fixed. So that it is safe. I will update this answer if I find an alternative method.

Comment: That would work or if you setup a server side client with a single email cloud function, basically for free if you have less than 2 million emails. You can also look into firebase hosting, which is also free.

Comment: Huthaifa, I have this doubt that how will I store the auth file of firebase? as now that is a sensitive data.

Comment: This worked out for me. But of course this is a general, very commonly used special case.